# Python loop not breaking out

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I expect the whole loop to exit when my `isQuit` variable is `"yes"` and customer becomes `False`. However, the current loop seems to be repeated until the `order_item` is in `menu_items`.

Can you please help me change my code so that the loops stop when the user wants to quit?

```
def order(menu):
    FISH_CHIPS_PRICES = menu
    menu_items = []

    for item in FISH_CHIPS_PRICES:
        menu_items.append(item.lower())

    orders = []
    customer = True
    while customer:
        orders.append({})

        for item in FISH_CHIPS_PRICES:
           orders[-1][item] = 0

        while True:
            while True:
                order_item = input("What do you want to buy?")
                if order_item.lower() not in menu_items:
                    print("Item:", order_item, "not available")
                    isQuit = input("Do you want to quit: yes / no:")
                    if isQuit == "yes":
                        customer = False
                else:
                    break
```

Comment: `break` can only break **one** layer of loop.

Comment: What do the two nested `while True` do?

Comment: @iBug, I often have code like `if (condition) if (condition) doSomething();` - I want to be *sure* that `condition` is true before proceeding :-)

Comment: Ok ok thanks. I thought the problem was something to do with variable scope and that the variable was not getting changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing this behavior because of the two infinite while loops enclosing to your `isQuit` variable. `break`ing out of a loop only stops the immediately enclosing loop.

One possible solution is to immediately `return` when `isQuit` is `"yes"`, which will exit the entire `order()` function.

```
# ...
isQuit = input("Do you want to quit: yes / no:")
if isQuit == "yes":
    return
```

Another possible solution is to remove the outer infinite while loop since it does not seem to serve any function.

Comment: I would argue that *both* of these changes should be made.

Comment: I would agree. A few _additional_ changes come to mind as well. But I don't really want to rewrite OP's entire function :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer only I just wanted to break out of the outer while loop and not the whole function cause there is some additional code.  Your comment and others helped me to identify that break only breaks the immediate loop so I had to break the outer loop at a stage when i was out of the inner loops.  I managed to finish it with your advice. http://pythonfiddle.com/fish-and-chips-program

Comment: Great! Glad I could help! Please consider accepting and upvoting the answer :)